# Files in folder displayed with PHP automatically inputted into php/html playlist

Tags: php, html, mp3, playlist

I have a what seems like simple issue. I would like to have my playlists auto populated with the files in a folder. So as mp3s are added to the folder the files are generated in the playlist.
I can display all the files in a folder and have the file names outputted on there own line using:

```
<?php
$dir = "app/vd/$val/";
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as &$file) {
    if ($file!='.' && $file!='..' )
    {
        echo $file.'<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

And I manually add files to the play list using:

```
<ul id="playlist" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<li mp3="app/vd/<?php echo $val ?>/whatever.mp3" ogg="app/vd/<?php echo $val ?>/whatever.ogg" artist="<?php echo $val ?>" title="<?php echo $val1 ?>" ></li>

<li mp3="app/vd/<?php echo $val ?>/whatever2.mp3" ogg="app/vd/<?php echo $val ?>/whatever2.ogg" artist="<?php echo $val ?>" title="<?php echo $val1 ?>" ></li>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want the .mp3's auto converted to .ogg, with artist and title extracted when you put an MP3 in the folder?

Comment: What specifically is your question?

Comment: No, I want the files listed in the folder to be inputted into the playlist so as files are added to a folder I do not have to add the mp3 filename.

Comment: The title and artist I am not worried about. Just so the filenames from a folder are auto adding a <li> to the "playlist". I can even go with out the ogg and just have mp3 and work up from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it between the ul tags ...

```
<ul id="playlist" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <?php
    $dir = "app/vd/$val/";
    $files = scandir( $dir );
    foreach ( $files as $file )
        if ( $file != '.' && $file != '..' )
            echo '<li mp3="app/vd/', $val, '/', $file,'" ogg="app/vd/', $val, '/', $file, '" artist="', $val, '" title="', $val1, '" ></li>';
    ?>
</ul>
```

or to make it look nicer

```
<?php $files = scandir( "app/vd/$val/" ); ?>
<ul id="playlist" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">  
    <?php foreach ( $files as $file )
        if ( $file != '.' && $file != '..' )
            echo "<li mp3=\"app/vd/$val/$file\" ogg=\"app/vd/$val/$file\" artist=\"$val\" title=\"$val1\" ></li>"; ?>
</ul>
```

P.S.: glob is a neat little function http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php
P.P.S: iterators on directories are neat, too